# wait/ stop in code execution until data getting from server

Tags: javascript, async-await, angular7

Component-1 has method-A when it get call in subscription, I need array list to check some conditions which is only get from method-Z in component-2. The data will get from DB so i need to wait Method-A condition call untill the arraylist will get.

[image: problem explain in flow chart]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, checkArrayList() is method which check weather the arraylist will gets data.
this.shareDataService.isLoading flag is true/false in method-z calls. when data load from db this.shareDataService.arrayList will get updaded.

```
let checkArrayList = async isLoad => {
            do { 
                isLoad = this.shareDataService.isLoading;// true/false in method-z  
                if (isLoad) {
                    await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 500))          
                } else {  
                    console.log(this.shareDataService.arrayList); //  data will get here
                }
            }
            while (isLoad) //when isload false while loop will break.
        }
```

`checkArrayList(this.shareDataService.isLoading); // calling function in method-A`

Comment: Why poll when Angular is built around RxJS? E.g. `this.shareDataService.arrayList$.subscribe((data) => { ... }))`.

Comment: Also we can Use forkJoin() here